# Should I use "require" or "load" when writing my own configuration?

Tags: init-file, customize, require, load, provide

I am following [this tutorial](http://tuhdo.github.io/emacs-tutor3.html#orgheadline20), and the author is doing something like this:

**`~/.emacs.d/init.el`**

```
;; add your modules path
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/custom/")

;; load your modules
(require 'setup-foo)
(require 'setup-bar)
......
```

**`~/.emacs.d/custome/setup-foo.el`**

```
(provide 'setup-foo)

;; various configuration settings for foo
```

**`~/.emacs.d/custome/setup-bar.el`**

```
(provide 'setup-bar)

;; various configuration settings for bar
```

I am wondering what's the advantage of doing this instead of simply `load`ing everything.

From my understanding, the point of using `provide`/`require` is to enable "lazy loading", so that a feature is only loaded when needed, but `init.el` always load the `setup-*.el` scripts, which renders this practice pointless to me.

I wouldn't say this question is a duplicate of [What does (require 'package) mean for emacs and how does it differ from load-file?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22717), though they're indeed related. My question ask on *how* to use the two different mechanisms, whereas the other one is about *what* they are.

Comment: Another advantage of provide/require is that it stops you from accidentally loading a file twice, but that too seems irrelevant to your case. So personally, I'd go for just loading the files. By the way, it is customary to put the `provide`  at the end of each file, so that if the file fails to load for some reason, the corresponding feature is not enabled – and a new `require` will retry loading the file.

Comment: @Harald remove the word "Another" from your comment, and I would say that is the answer. `provide`/`require` isn't related to "lazy"/autoloading.

Comment: @npostavs Good point. Stefan already provided an answer to that effect, so that is good enough.

Comment: Also, `require` lets you do a "soft require", which does not raise an error if the library is not available: `(require 'foo nil t)`. And please see the doc, starting perhaps with the Emacs manual, node [How Programs Do Loading](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html).

Comment: Your latest edit would have been more appropriate as a comment, I think.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen My question was marked a “possible duplicate”, so I got a notification asking me to “edit to clarify” :P

Comment: Yes, but the edit does not clarify the question; you are merely arguing that the question is not a duplicate. Nothing wrong with that, but a comment is more appropriate for such discussion. (In my opinion – others may disagree.)

Comment: @Drew `load` also lets you do a "soft load": `(load "foo" t)`.

Comment: @npostavs: True.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of `require` is not lazy-loading (that would be `autoload` instead).  Instead, the purpose is to avoid loading the same package multiple times.

In the case of config files, which of `load` or `require` is preferable is unclear and will depend on your particular use case (but I think in most cases the difference will be negligible).

Comment: I think it‘s no problem to describe `require` as lazy-loading, as the manual puts "provide and require are an alternative to autoload for loading files automatically." And the canonical use case is to put `require` in the body some other function definition to ensure loading. Both `require` and `autoload` provide an idempotent trigger to make lazy-loading possible.