Using "provide" with value of a variable
I want to use provide with the value of a variable. I can't have it written it down as text.
For example, I want to provide the symbol: foo. Normally, I would do:
(provide 'foo)

But now I have the following:
(setq bar 'foo)

And I have to provide bar's value. I tried the following:
(setq bar 'foo)
(provide `',bar)

But I get an error. How could I go about doing this?

'foo is shorthand for (quote foo).  The lisp reader reads and interns the canonical symbols quote and foo, and when that quote form is evaluated it returns the value that the lisp reader generated: the symbol foo.  So 'foo is a form which evaluates to the symbol foo.  And in your case bar is also a form which evaluates to the symbol foo.  Hence (provide bar).

After (setq bar 'foo), you can say (provide bar): provide is an ordinary function, so it evaluates its argument, bar in this case:
(provide bar) ;; ==> foo
(featurep bar) ;; ==> t
;; ... or equivalently
(featurep 'foo) ;; ==> t

featurep is also an ordinary function, so it evaluates its argument. In the second line, its argument is bar (unquoted), so the evaluated argument is the value of bar which is foo. In the third line, the argument is 'foo: quoting inhibits evaluation, so the value of 'foo is the symbol foo as well.

EDIT (in answer to the comments by Chris Bouchard):
You most certainly could say (require 'foo): do C-h f require to see how its argument is used (Hint: the file that contains the module would need to be in one of the directories specified by load-path and it would need to be named foo.el - as long as that's the case, require would work. All that provide does is add a symbol to the features list, so that a second require does not have to do any work - but it does have to provide the symbol (feature) that require asked for, otherwise require complains (basically, it checks the feature list for foo, and if it does not find it there, it loads the file and then checks the feature list again to make sure that the file it loaded provided the feature it asked for).
So as long as the file does (provide 'foo) or equivalent, everything will work fine. But note that if the file does
(setq bar 'foo)
...
(provide bar)

that IS equivalent: in both cases, the feature name is foo: that is added to the feature list and that is what require asks for.
That's the most common use case for require but you could also use a different filename through an optional argument: (require 'foo "bar.el"). Then bar.el could (provide 'foo) - or, assuming that it had set bar to have the value foo, it could (provide bar) - same thing.
The main point however is that both require and provide are ordinary functions, ordinary functions evaluate their arguments and their arguments could be "constants" (quoted symbols) or "variables" (symbols which contain the "constant" in their value cells)1. eval is used to evaluate an argument of an ordinary function when the function is called: if eval encounters a "constant" (a quoted symbol), it produces that symbol as the value; if it encounters a variable, it consults the value cell of the symbol and produces that as its value  (and if it encounters something more complicated, like a function application, it might call itself recursively to do the evaluation):
(setq bar 'foo)

(func 'foo) ;; the value of the argument that the function sees here
              ;; is `foo'
(func bar)  ;; the value of the argument that the function sees here
              ;; is *also* `foo'

As far as the function is concerned, the two calls are identical.
See also @phils's comment under the question.

Footnotes:
[1] They could be more complicated things as well, like function applications, but that does not concern us here.

I haven't tried it, but would this confuse the byte compiler and/or autoloader? If I understand correctly, they operate at the syntactic level.

I don't really understand your concern: what is the scenario you are worried about? What is "this" that would confuse the byte compiler or the autoloader? What problem(s) do you foresee? Why would "operating at the syntactic level" (which IIUC the compiler does indeed do, but the autoloader does not) cause problems?

It's ok—I'm not raising a red alarm or anything! But for example, if a module used (provide bar) like this, presumably you wouldn't be able to say (require 'foo) to load that module—elisp could only know that bar would evaluate to 'foo by evaluating the module. I was wondering if there were any other gotchas like that that OP should be aware of, because that sort of limitation feels important to call out in a complete answer.

I did misspeak by referencing the autoloader—in my mind require fell in the same bucket as autoloading (since it's referring to a feature symbol and not a file), but after re-reading the docs I see they're separate mechanisms.

I tried to correct my comment by deleting and adding a corrected version but that changed the sequence so it didn't make much sense any longer. So I deleted all the comments and will edit the answer to provide (I hope!) a cogent and correct explanation.

@ChrisBouchard Maybe https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22718/454 will also help to clarify.  (NickD's explanation here is much more detailed, though.)
